# Can we plot multiple time series in one plot using hydroTSM?

Tags: r

I have daily precipitation data in the following format:

```
> head(df)
    I_2004   G_2004    T_2004       Date
1 3628.79853 2199.310 12741.413 2004-01-01
2 1556.66704 4322.884  5464.395 2004-01-02
3   20.43379 5592.103    72.998 2004-01-03
4  265.94247 8145.041   942.344 2004-01-04
5  914.93958 9668.531  3227.579 2004-01-05
6 2585.63558 6825.905  9043.866 2004-01-06
```

usually I plot the time series of all 3 variables together using ggplot2:

```
  dfmelt<-melt(df,id.vars="Date")
ggplot(dfmelt,aes(x=Date,y=value,
                  col=variable,group=12))+
  labs(title='ANNUAL')+
  geom_line()
```

I have used hydroTSM to plot ts but never multi variable one. I was wondering if there was any way to achieve this using packages like hydroTSM?

my current method requires subsetting and doing so for multiple years is time consuming. I'm hoping to shorten this using hydroTSM or any other suitable package.
my aim to is plot monthly and seasonal time series plots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use a larger data frame below (see Note at end) so that it is possible to display month plots. Convert the data frame df to a zoo series -- hydroTSM makes zoo available -- and use autoplot.zoo .  Use aggregate with tail or mean to create a monthly plot and convert that to ts to create the seasonal plot. Except for ggplot2 the following only uses packages already pulled in by hydroTSM.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(hydroTSM)

z <- read.zoo(df, index = "Date")
autoplot(z) # separate panels

autoplot(z, facets = NULL) # single panel

# monthly plot
zm <- aggregate(z, as.yearmon, tail, 1, frequency = 12)
autoplot(zm)

# for seasonal plot
tt <- as.ts(zm)
nc <- ncol(tt)
opar <- par(mfrow = c(nc, 1), mar = c(2, 4, 0, 4))
for(j in 1:nc) monthplot(tt[, j], ylab = colnames(tt)[j])
par(opar)
```

[image: screenshot]

### Note

`df` in reproducible form.  Larger than in question so that monthly plots can be shown.

```
set.seed(123)
n <- 700
df <- data.frame(I_2004 = rnorm(n), 
                 G_2004 = rnorm(n),
                 T_2004 = rnorm(n),
                 Date = as.Date("2004-01-01") + 1:n - 1)
```